# Android How to add Tabs dynamically from json using viewpager

Tags: android

How to add Tabs dynamically from json using viewpager at load page on Mainactivity and show corresponding data on gridview.
I already try this ,just static method.

can i add dynamically tabs from json? and it's data corresponding.

```
 ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    if (viewPager != null) {
        setupViewPager(viewPager);
    }
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    ViewPager viewPager1 = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager1);
    if (viewPager1 != null) {
        setupViewPager1(viewPager1);
    }
    TabLayout tabLayout1 = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs1);
    tabLayout1.setupWithViewPager(viewPager1);

}

public void setTabFragmentTwo(String t){
    TabFragmentTwo = t;
}

public String getTabFragmentTwo(){
    return TabFragmentTwo;
}


private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    Adapter adapter = new Adapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new OneFragment(), "Category 1");
    adapter.addFragment(new TwoFragment(), "Category 2");
    adapter.addFragment(new ThreeFragment(), "Category 3");
    adapter.addFragment(new ThreeFragment(), "Category 3");
    adapter.addFragment(new ThreeFragment(), "Category 3");
    adapter.addFragment(new ThreeFragment(), "Category 3");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
static class Adapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragments = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitles = new ArrayList<>();

    public Adapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragments.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitles.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragments.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitles.get(position);
    }
}
private void setupViewPager1(ViewPager viewPager) {
    Adapter1 adapter1 = new Adapter1(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter1.addFragment(new Fragment_quick_bill(), "Quick Bill");
    adapter1.addFragment(new Fragment_addvnced_bill(), "Addvanc-Bil");

    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter1);
}
static class Adapter1 extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragments = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitles = new ArrayList<>();

    public Adapter1(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragments.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitles.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragments.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitles.get(position);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can easily add tabs dynamically:

```
private void addTab(String title) {
        mTabLayout.addTab(mTabLayout.newTab().setText(title));
        mPagerAdapter.addTabPage(title);
}
```

and addTabPage method to your PagerAdapter(tabItems are item list).

```
public void addTabPage(String title) {
      tabItems.add(title);
      notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

// complete class(check how using for loop I am able to add 3 tabs dynamically now you can call above mentioned method wherever you need like getting category list from api or using button click etc.)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TabLayout mTabLayout;
    ViewPager mViewPager;
    Adapter mPagerAdapter;
    List<String> tabItems = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        mTabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);

        mPagerAdapter = new Adapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);

        for(int i=1; i<=3; i++){
            addTab("Tab"+ i);
        }

        mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);


    }

    private void addTab(String title) {
        mTabLayout.addTab(mTabLayout.newTab().setText(title));
        addTabPage(title);
    }

    public void addTabPage(String title) {
        tabItems.add(title);
        mPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    class Adapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public Adapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return OneFragment.newInstance("param1","param2");
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return tabItems.size();
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return tabItems.get(position);
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: how can i create PagerAdapter?

Comment: i can't call ... mPagerAdapter.addTabPage(title);

Comment: @KpAbhijith please see my updated answer there tabItems are list of items.

Comment: hello sir,..
where do i call  addTab(String title) method.

Comment: @KpAbhijith check my updated answer you will get better understanding

Comment: @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return OneFragment.newInstance("param1","param2");
        }

what is contained in newInstance("param1","param2") on OneFragment.

Comment: Showing following errors:

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' on a null object reference

Comment: **You need to have newInstance method in your fragment**.  Just create your fragment using android studio it will automatically create this method else create method yourself or you can `return just new OneFragment` only.

Comment: I created like this,

Comment: public static Fragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {

        return null;
    }

Comment: `public static OneFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        return new OneFragment();
    }`